# How do I pair adjacent cells with one another in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am attempting to create an efficient way to log our customer orders. So far what I've done is have the customer names in the 1st column. Contact details in the 2nd. Then in the sequential columns I have created drop down boxes to select the appropriate product and in the following column is the quantity.

Because of how customers order, the same products may not necessarily be in the same column Meaning it may read something like this...

Name. Number. Product1. Qty Product2. Qty. Product3. Qty

Name. Number. Product 3. Qty. Product 1. Qty. Product 2. Qty.

Name Number.. Product 3. Qty.

Name. Number. Product 2. Qty. Product 3. Qty.

So what I want to do is create a totals list for each product by pairing it with the relevant qty. But I'm struggling to find an appropriate method. So far I have found the means to count how many time each product is ordered, but not able to match that with the qty.

So if someone can help me do so I would much appreciate it.

p.s. I am using Excel 2007

Answer (score 0):

It won't be a short formula as you need to specify each of the columns that need to be summed, but the best function would be `SUMIF` which uses this syntax:

```
SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])
```

Applied to your data you would need to also use `SUM` to total the totals of each column, for example if your data looked like this:

```
 | A     | B      |  C        | D   |  E        | F   |  G        | H
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1| Name  | Number |  1        | Qty |  2        | Qty |  3        | Qty
2| Test1 | 123    |  Product1 | 4   |  Product2 | 5   |  Product3 | 2
3| Test2 | 456    |  Product3 | 2   |  Product1 | 1   |  Product2 | 5
4| Test3 | 789    |  Product3 | 3   |           |     |           |  
5| Test4 | 112    |  Product2 | 2   |  Product3 | 1   |           |
```

You could use the following formula to total all the Products named "Product1":

```
=SUM(SUMIF(C2:C5,"Product1",D2:D5),SUMIF(E2:E5,"Product1",F2:F5),SUMIF(G2:G5,"Product1",H2:H5))
```

Which would equate to `5` using the example data.